# Passing Run time object types in side List<T>

Tags: c#, .net

```
object obj = new Customer();
Type Ty = obj.GetType();
Validator<Ty> cusValidator = valFactory.CreateValidator<Ty>();
```

**getting Error here**

is it possible?

Comment: You might want to be clearer on a) what you want to achieve and b) what the exact error is.

Comment: Please show syntax of `CreateValidator` method and especially any generic type constraints. Also declaration of type `Ty` might be helpful as well

Comment: The generic type of `T` must be specified at compile time if you want strong-typing at compile time and little/no casting. You can use reflection to close open generics, but then you have to cast around or use dynamic or reflection to get any worthwhile use out of it. When it gets to this stage I tend to think my design has gone wrong somewhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it is. But not with compile-time type checking. Your runtime type `Ty` is not a valid compile-time type argument. It can be done with reflection, using the `MakeGenericType` method without the safety of the compile time check:

```
object obj = new Customer();
Type ty = obj.GetType();
MethodInfo validatorFactory = valFactory.GetType()
                               .GetMethod("CreateValidator")
                               .MakeGenericType(ty);
var cusValidator = validatorFactory.Invoke(valFactory, null);
```

But you cannot type something like `Validator<ty>` -- you have to use `var` or `dynamic`. Be aware that now the type is object:

```
// true:
cusValidator.GetType() == typeof(object)
```

You may introduce a non-generic Validator interface to allow the invocation of methods on `cusValidator` where you insert a base class of all your `Customer` (and so on) classes to validate it. You can't cast to `Validator<ty>`.

Comment: `var` is the most beneficial when you work with complicated generic signatures. But contrary to `dynamic`, the `var` adds nothing to the subject here -- the `Invoke` simply returns an `Object`, so just `object cusV` tells everything.

Comment: @quetzalcoatl Of course you're right. The return value of Invoke must then be casted to an interface which is helpful for the work with validatorFactory - one non-generic `Validator` interface for example.

Comment: Thanks for answering... But but to call the function of the object cusValidator. I have to cal cusValidator.Validate(obj); because here cusValidator is var datatype, so the cusValidator.Validate() function is not accessible.

Comment: @SukeshChand: so use what I or Matten were talking about: dynamic or common interface. If you make your `class Validator<T>` implement an interface of `public interface IValidate{ void Validate(object); }` then you will be able to cast the 'cusValidator' to "IValidate" and call that method regardless of what exact type the Validator actually is. Note however that the interface **may not be generic over the "T" from Validator<T>** or else you will hit the same problem again. On the other hand, use of `dynamic cusVal` will allow you to call "cusVal.Validate(x)" but without checks at compilation.

Comment: @SukeshChand: in fact, with `dynamic cusVal`, even 'cusVal.skjdegfj3q4gdajwehfkjshfdkf(obj)' will **compile**, but obviously it will **crash** at runtime (well, unless you actually has such method out there:)). Hence, I strongly suggest to use simple common interface.